# What is Mathematica option to check whether trigonometric equality is true or false?

Tags: mathematica

What is the TrueQ analog that recognizes trigonometric equalities?

Comment: This should be posted on mathematica.SE and not on math.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `SameQ`

For example :

```
SameQ[Sin[Pi/6], 1/2]
```

Comment: thanks that's what i waas looking for!